# How to compare attribute values from different classes?

Tags: scala

I've two classes with a few attributes that have the same names, for example:

```
case class Rect(x: Int, y: Int)
case class Squa(x: Int, y: Int)
```

To compare it I do:

```
val r = new Rect(2, 2)
val s = new Squa(2, 2)

r.x == s.x && r.y == x.y
```

If I have "N" attributes I have to compare one by one, is there a way to compare all attributes at once since they have the same name? I've tried:

```
r.asInstanceOf[Squa] eq s
```

But this gives me the error:

> class Rect cannot be cast to class Squa (Rect and Squa are in unnamed module of loader scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader @3b81a1bc)

The running example: https://repl.it/join/eegmixii-rafa_acioly

Comment: You could make both inherit from a trait, making them easier to compare

Comment: can you post an answer with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`productIterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html#productIterator:Iterator%5BAny%5D). For example you can do:

```
r.productIterator.sameElements(s.productIterator)
```

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WXiQ0uheSY6c1hRQFOJxCw)

Another option you have is to share a trait between the 2. Let's define:

```scala
trait Base extends Ordered[Base] {
  val x: Int
  val y: Int

  override def compare(that: Base): Int = {
    if (x != that.x) {
      x - that.x
    } else {
      y - that.y
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can test it with:

```
println("Rect(2,2).compareTo(Squa(2,2)): " + Rect(2,2).compareTo(Squa(2,2))) // 0
println("Rect(2,2) > Squa(2,2) " + (Rect(2,2) > Squa(2,2))) // false
println("Rect(2,2) >= Squa(2,2) " + (Rect(2,2) >= Squa(2,2))) // true
println("Rect(3,2) >= Squa(2,2) " + (Rect(3,2) >= Squa(2,2))) // true
println("Rect(3,2) >= Squa(2,3) " + (Rect(3,2) >= Squa(2,3))) // true
println("Rect(2,3) >= Squa(3,2) " + (Rect(2,3) >= Squa(3,2))) // false
```

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OpdtfLePQDK9cc0cbEnWIw).

Comment: Thank you, what if I need to compare some attributes but not all of them? can I "filter" the ones that I want to compare or maybe ignore the ones that I don't want to?

Comment: In StackOverflow every question is about 1 topic. If you have another question, you can ask it in another post. If this answer fulfils your query, you can accept it. If you have any queries regarding the topic at the question you can ask it.

Comment: I've posted another question as you suggested, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593358/how-to-compare-all-attributes-between-classes-expect-a-few

Comment: @RafaAcioly, doesn't the `Base` trait solves your new problem as well?

Comment: I don't think so, if I have N attributes I would need to check one by one, the main question is about not having to check one by one.

Comment: @RafaAcioly How would you like to differ between the members that you want to compare to the ones you don't?

Comment: I was thinking in exclude by the attribute name (maybe) but I don't know how to do this in scala :(

Comment: The best you can do is define the members you want to compare at the trait. Don't try to use reflection for that.