# How to compare all attributes between classes except a few?

Tags: scala

I've got the answer on how to compare all attributes between two classes [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573743/how-to-compare-attribute-values-from-different-classes?noredirect=1#comment114182238_64573743), but my classes also have `DateTime` attributes that are defined on the fly, this way I cannot compare them because the `DateTime` on each class will have seconds of difference.

How can I compare two classes attributes excluding some attributes? In this example, excluding the attribute `z`.

```
case class Rect(x: Int, y: Int, z: Double)
case class Squa(x: Int, y: Int, z: Double)
```

Comment: Did you try the trait suggested at the link you attached? If you add there `z: Double` to the trait, it solves exactly your question.

Comment: Actually, the trait should work as is, since it doesn't need to know about `z`. Unless your classes have a ton of attributes and you want some kind of macro, that approach should work